# How to enforce 256-bit encryption on personal information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

We are building a Rails application and one of our clients had asked if we are using industry-standard 256-bit encryption to ensure the confidentiality of personal information.

Are there are any gems which can be used to enforce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enforce the use of ssl in rails. A good summary how to do this can be found in http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

Second you have to configure your webserver, so that it forces clients to use aes256 for secured connections. If you are using apache, you might start reading here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html

That should be about it.